# How to replace the value of one cell with another based on whether a word exists in a specific cell

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a basic question. I have a one column which represents a quantity. The cell to the right is a new column that will contain a word. I want to search cells in one column for the word and if it appears replace the word, let's say "foil" with the value of the cell to the left. A2 represents the cell A2, and I am checking B2. This formula is not working. I want the value of cell A2, not literally "A2"

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("*foil*",B2,1),"A2"),"0")
```

Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate any and all help with this.

Comment: It might be easier to add some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: `"A2"` should be `A2`  Sample data would definitely help though

Comment: you probably also want `""` or `0` rather than `"0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are using `SEARCH()` function you do not need to use `wild card`. Remove double quote from `"A2"` so that formula can show data of `A2` cell instead of text `A2`. See below...

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Foil",B2,1),A2),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Harun24HR! This is the exact result I was hoping to get. I thought I put that formula like the one you described, but I guess not because I was not able to get the above result which is exactly what I had hoped to get when I asked for help.

Comment: How do you add the sample table you used above? Is that from excel or google sheets?

Comment: It will work to both desktop excel sheet as well as google sheet. I used sample from desktop excel.